# Wired network problem 13.04

Tags: networking, 13.04, wired

I used to not be able to connect with my wired connection on Ubuntu 13.04. It worked magically sometimes and I clicked around in the settings. Now it's working consistently. I remember playing around with VPN but I didn't change any major settings. 
As I want to install another system now, I want to know what it is in order to figure out, what to do in the future. As I boot into Linux Mint on a USB I'm having the same problem, there I have not been able to figure out what to do in order to get it working.

I'm connecting to a dorm network. Other people living here seem to have no problem connecting with their windows machines. Also there are no torrent files/connections working. I see connecting peers for some files, but it doesn't start seeding.

I hugely appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

The commands were run on the consistently working machine on Ubuntu 13.04 on a Thinkpad x230i.

---

***lspci | grep Ethernet***

```
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (rev 04)
```

***dmesg | grep eth***

```
[    1.015232] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: (PCI Express:2.5GT/s:Width x1) 3c:97:0e:b7:00:9c
[    1.015235] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
[    1.015273] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: MAC: 10, PHY: 11, PBA No: 1000FF-0FF
[   14.138549] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   15.585540] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   15.585915] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   17.134208] e1000e: eth0 NIC Link is Up 100 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: None
[   17.134215] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: 10/100 speed: disabling TSO
[   17.134248] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
```

***ifconfig eth0***

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 3c:97:0e:b7:00:9c  
          inet addr:141.70.83.230  Bcast:141.70.83.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::3e97:eff:feb7:9c/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:33801 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:19683 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:31126117 (31.1 MB)  TX bytes:3483515 (3.4 MB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:f2500000-f2520000
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`echo on | sudo tee /sys/class/net/eth0/device/power/control`

This should definitely solve the whole problem...after its done, exit sudo and pull out, then plug in the ethernet cable again